What are the lessons/significances of the Matriarchs growing up under idol worshipping parents?
Unlike Yitzchak and Yaacov, Sarah, Rivka, Rachel and Leah, as well as the latters' handmaidens, all grew up similar to Avraham, in homes of idol worship.
Why did Hashem arrange things this way? What lesson(s) do we draw from this fact, about them?

Perhaps that we have free will and can overcome the way that we were brought up?

@MosesSupposes thanks for the great answer! I was actually intending something else by the question though, and you made me realise I wasn't clear sorry! Edited ^

Maybe it has something to do with this famous Maharal?


Who says HaShem arranged things this way? HaShem sent the animals to the ark, He didn't send the wives to the patriarchs. All of them got their own wives.

I would say the best answer to this question is exemplified with Moses. Why did God only choose Moses to be the prophet after Moses went to live with the High Priest of Midyan for decades? Usually we would say of such people that they would end up less "Jewish." But instead we find Moses seems to be ready for his mission only after Yitro's influence and the influence of Zipporah and his experience as a Shepherd. I would have thought Moses would have been a better prophet by living in Mitzrayim amongst his people, but it turns out the opposite was true.

I'll take you an example one step farther. Rahab the harlot, not only a pagan woman, but a literal prostitute on top of it. We see from her story how righteous she was, how she cared for her family and the lives of the Israelite people. Our tradition says she ended up marrying Yehoshua, the de facto leader after Moses.


The lesson I take away from all of these examples is that God wants us to understand the following. Being a good person when you are surrounded by good people is like being a candle in a well lit room. How much light are you really adding? How much positive change to the world are you really bringing? And how much of your light is actually yours being emanated from within you, and how much is just the light of the overall room?
But those who come from darkness, or who live in darkness, their light is entirely different. Even a single candle can pierce a dark space and those who see it know that the light comes from the person themselves, and not their surroundings. The darkness intensifies the light so to speak.
I'm not sure Moses would ever have been ready if he stayed in Mitzrayim. And I'm not sure we would have survived as a people if not for our matriarchs.

Thoughtful answer that is filled with things I agree with and like. However, it doesn't answer the about them part of the question, which to me is the main part.
